# HFP/HSP profile in linux

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez, pulseaudio

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and already installed BlueZ 5.37, PulseAudio 10.0, and ofono 1.20 (clone from github).

And I need to use phone like modem for transmitting my phone calls to computer. I paired my telephone with PC, made device trust and connect (all actions are successfully). I think problem with ofono, because I can play music (which use the A2DP) but if i want use hends free or headset profile - I have no sound on PC.

In pacmd (PulseAudio console tool) list-cards I see my bluetooth device, but Headset Audio Gateway HFP/HSP is not avalible. Also I tested it on different devices and computers.

Thank you in advice.

Answer (score 7):

I've solved in this way:

1. Install `ofono`
2. In `/etc/pulse/default.pa` find the line `load-module module-bluetooth-discover` and change it to `load-module module-bluetooth-discover headset=ofono`.
3. If the user `pulse` is not a member of group `bluetooth`, then add it: `sudo useradd -g bluetooth pulse`
4. **VERY IMPORTANT:** add this to `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/ofono.conf` before `</busconfig>`:

   ```
   <policy user="pulse">
    <allow send_destination="org.ofono"/>
   </policy>
   ```

See: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Bluetooth/

The good news: Now in `pavucontrol` I can see that the profile changes automatically from A2DP to HSP / HFP if I make a phone call, and then it magically returns to A2DP!

The bad news: it works only one time per booting (and checking if `ofonod` is running), then I have to reboot my Debian system.

Comment: After configured ofono, the sound on my headphones started to work well, but, I don't see the headphone's microphone anymore. Any idea?

Comment: I just want to note: I had to use` sudo usermod -aG bluetooth pulse` in lieu of step 3.

Answer (score 3):

**My Solution:**

I just found my solution in Fedora 26, using Plantronics Legend and Pluggable Bluetooth USB, after a lot of searching.

I am going back through my history, and updating threads with my solution where I can.  This worked for me, direct from Plugable (which is the USB module I am using).

*See this post:  [plugable-usb-bluetooth-adapter-solving-hfphsp-profile-issues-on-linux](https://plugable.com/2014/06/23/plugable-usb-bluetooth-adapter-solving-hfphsp-profile-issues-on-linux/)*

**Command Summary per Above Link:**

`wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/plugable/bin/fw-0a5c_21e8.hcd`

`sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/brcm`

`sudo mv fw-0a5c_21e8.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM20702A0-0a5c-21e8.hcd`

`sudo cp /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM20702A0-0a5c-21e8.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd`

Then reboot.

Comment: I was hitting similar issues with a plugable bluetooth usb adapter - after doing this firmware update, I can switch back and forth between the two profiles without problems.

Answer (score 0):

HSP/HFP Profile not available for Bluetooth headset in Fedora 20, was available in Fedora 19 change the device and test it again

[SOLVING HFP/HSP AND A2DP PROFILE ISSUES ON LINUX](http://plugable.com/2014/06/23/plugable-usb-bluetooth-adapter-solving-hfphsp-profile-issues-on-linux/)